# After new awareness, a word similar to "disillusionment", but +positive as there is still magic involved

Tags: single-word-requests

After understanding a `trick` or `ploy` involved in a `magic trick`

`we gain insight` into the mechanics, `but lose the feeling` that magic is real.

When we see how a trick or slight-of-hand works, we become 
"**disillusioned**".

By contrast:
Before studying computer science, `computers seemed equally mysterious` to me.

Now that I understand the underlying principles, I know that computers are not in fact magic.

However, I have a newfound appreciation,

`and they seem even more magical now`, only in a new and different way.

The best (non) word for this that comes to mind is:
"**reillusionment**".

Example:

> After becoming indoctrinated into the academic realm of computer arcitecture and systems design, I became `reillusioned <-- (better word here)` : suddenly computers and the Universe were even more mystical to me in a way I'd never expected.

Is there a better (and real) word to capture this feeling?

Comment: How about enamored or re-enamored?

Comment: oOoo like this one too! "Falling in love with" all over again, but also maybe seeing the object of your love in a new light. Works really well. Re-enamored. Thanks for this

Comment: Also a great opposite to the bitter connotation of "disillusioned"

Comment: OH MY EYES! Please never use backticks to make ugly blue monospace on ELU. Use italics for mentions. Those are not code and should not be marked as though they are. Plus it looks just awful.

Comment: it's to highlight, through text since vocal tone isn't an option here, the important nuance of the connotation of the words

Comment: Good to know best practices on this subsite though. Please keep it civil.

Comment: Plus it makes skimming + re-reading more fluid. Not sure why you'd let such a useful highlighting functionality go to waste.

Comment: [ http://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice ] "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn."

Answer (score 3):

perhaps *enlightened* could work here. Once one understands a system, they can truly marvel at how amazing/mysterious it all is.

Comment: oOOo that's a good one. I think besides "reillusioned" this is probably the best word for it that I know of. It has implications of both rational knowledge + connotations of spiritual awareness. Still hoping for a word I don't know yet, but this one is excellent.